# How to fix "No SELinux security context (/etc/crontab)" issue?

Tags: cron, yocto, selinux

I have enabled SELinux in my yocto project(warrior branch) but **`cron`** is not functioning because of some SELinux context isuue. I am using `minimum` SELinux policy. Here is the error from `/var/log/messages`

```
Oct  9 04:50:01 panther2 cron.info crond[261]: ((null)) No SELinux security context (/etc/crontab)        
Oct  9 04:50:01 panther2 cron.info crond[261]: (root) FAILED (loading cron table)
```

Here are some contexts for relevant files,

```
root@panther2:~# ps -efZ | grep cron
system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0   root       464     1  0 04:54 ?    00:00:00 /usr/sbin/crond -n

root@panther2:~# ls -lZ /etc/crontab 
-rw-------. 1 root root system_u:object_r:unconfined_t:s0 653 Oct  9  2019 /etc/crontab

root@panther2:~# ls -lZ /usr/sbin/crond 
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root system_u:object_r:unlabeled_t:s0 68160 Oct  9  2019 /usr/sbin/crond
```

Any help? Thanks !!

Comment: This seems to be a bug(https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=591587) but couldn't find proper fix.

Answer (score 0):

unconfined_t is a type to associate with active entities (processes). You associated that with /etc/crontab which is a passive entity (a file). Processes do things and thus need permissions. Objects (passive entities) get operated on by active entities and so types associated with files generally have no permissions associated with them, with the exception of permission to associate with a filesystem where applicable.

unlabeled_t indicates that /usr/sbin/crond either has an invalid or no label at all associated with it.

Cron is SELinux aware. Cron runs tasks on behalf of either the system or on behalf of users (using pam_selinux). These tasks generally get run with permissions different than the permissions associated with the context of crond itself. Crond tries to determine what context to run a given task with by looking at the label of the crontab (/ett/crontab is the crontab for system tasks), and then using that label to determine what context to run the task with using libselinux API. It determines whether the type associated with a crontab can be used to run a task with a given context, and then it determines whether it has permissions to run the task with a given context.

In your case above crond determined (with help of the SELinux API) that the context associated with the system crontab (/etc/crontab) could not be used to run tasks with the context it wanted to run the task with.

You need to make sure that the context associated with /etc/crontab is valid and that it can be used as an entrypoint to the context you want crond to run the task with.

If you want an example then look at the cron policy and cron context configuration files enclosed with reference policy.